# Inequalities and equations - creating sets from quadratic equations.

Tags: inequality, quadratics

My question is just making sure that my working is correct and that I understand properly (self teaching, can get confused...)

So question :

Find the set of values for which

$$x^2 -4x-12 < 0$$

I can factor this to

$$(x-2)(x+6) < 0$$

So this means that $x = 2$ or $x = -6$

This then get expressed as

$$-2<x<6$$

I can't really explain why though...

Is this because $x - 2 = 0$ so $x > -2$ ...?

If I create a graph of $y = (x-2)(x+6)$ the range of values between the two x intercepts are $-6 $ to $2$....

So from that I would expect the equalities to be

$$-6<x<2$$

not

$$-2<x<6$$

I'm not sure what I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Your factorisation should be $(x+2)(x-6)$

Comment: dear me how stupid... so then it all makes sense, there's no confusion after that really... should I delete this post? I'm not too sure on the convention there... thanks though Mark.

Comment: Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the two roots that satisfy $x^2 - 4x - 12 = 0$. Assume $x_1 < x_2$. What you should do is then divide the real number line in three intervals, namely $(-\infty,x_1)$, $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(x_2,+\infty)$ and find out for each interval if the expression $x^2 - 4x - 12$ is positive or negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\;x^2-4x-12=(x+2)(x-6)$$

is a parabola that opens up (a "smiling" one) or a convex upwards one, and it vanishes at $\;x=-2,6\;$ . If you make even a raw drawing of this, you will clearly see that

$$x^2-4x-12<0\iff -2<x<6$$

The above's already a complete, mathematical formal proof **if** you've already studied quadratic functions and parabolas from a geometric/algebraic point of view.

One can also prove the inequality in a purely algebraic way:

$$(x+2)(x-6)<0\iff \begin{cases}x+2>0\;\;\text{and}\;\;x-6<0\\or\\x+2<0\;\;\text{and}\;\;x-6>0\end{cases}$$

The second possibility above is impossible as this would imply $\;x>-2\;\;\wedge\;\;x>6\;$ , and there's no such a thing, so it must be the first one, which is the same we got in the first part above.

Comment: Thanks for that Timbuc! I messed up the factoring and then spent ages trying to reinvent maths for some stupid reason! :/